# add key: value to JSON Data in nodejs module function under race conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, promise, q

Here is what I actually try to do in a node.js and socket.io server:

```
var Q = require('q');

module.exports.pushMyData = function (socket, RawData, row_id) {

return Q.fcall(function () {
    layout.row_id = row_id;
}).then(function (resultData) {
    socket.emit('resultData', resultData);
    console.log("resultData emited ++++++:" + resultData);

});
};
```

In the scope of the module.exports.pushMyData function I can proof that all parameters deliver correct values and socket is ok, too.
The other params look like this:

```
rawData = {"myset":{"id":"22","item":"150"},
       "myOtherset":{"hash":"55","branch":"150"},
       "myid":"15"}
row_id = 234
```

Now I want to put the row_id simply into the RawData:
it should after that be emitted via socket as the resultData like that:

```
resultData = {"my_set":{"id":"22","item":"150"},
       "my_other_set":{"hash":"55","branch":"150"},
       "my_id":"15",
       "row_id":234} // as a key value pair
```

I am actually confused because I find no way to fill the rawData literal with the row_id key/value, so that I suspect it has a race condition issue.
might be that the socket.emit starts before row_id was added to rawData.
It's a miracle to me ;-)
My tryout with Q seems not to be the right way. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using promises? You're doing nothing asynchronous there. Is `socket.emit` called at all with this code?

Comment: yes it is called and I receive the pushed Dataset if I do not use promises

Comment: But I'm to stupid to get the "row_id" = xyz into the rawData.

Comment: If there is something asynchronous going on, please show the code that constructs the `RawData` and calls that `pushMyData` function.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any promises here. Just assign the property:

```
module.exports.pushMyData = function (socket, rawData, row_id) {
    rawData.row_id = row_id;
    socket.emit('resultData', rawData);
    console.log("resultData emited ++++++:", rawData);
};
```

Comment: Bergi, thanks, but this is exactly the code I used before. This code doesn't work. I explain.. In the scope of the module.exports.pushMyData() I have all the params exactly available at runtime. I am able to console.log them all. The socket.emit('resultData', rawData) emits just the virgin rawData without the row_id. So I think it has a race condition issue. Maybe we should build a plunkr to sho this. But how with socket.io ;-)

Comment: It seems to be a real issue :-(( I know and like always it burns,,,, Always the small shit happens so that all the workflow stops. It's dataworld

Comment: OK, as I said, please show me what exactly `rawData` is and where it comes from. Also try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(rawData))` to see whether it really is available or only the console sees it.